# Remover primeiro e último caractere de uma string

Tags: java, string, substring

Preciso remover o primeiro e o último caractere de uma variável `String`, tentei utilizar `substring` para isso, porém está dando o seguinte erro:

```
String index out of range
```

E não estou encontrando um modo de fazer isso, fiz isso até agora:

```
conteudoLote.replace("[", "(").replace("]",")").substring(1,(conteudoLote.length()-1))
```

Conteúdo da variável:

```
((1,'SCAB17003066B','Suprimento com Defeito e com Resíduo','Lexmark International','60FBX00','Fraco',15),(1,'SCAB160632D9FRET','Vazio','Lexmark International','50FBX00',null,50), (1,'SCAB17003066B','Vazio','Lexmark International','60FBX00',null,null), (1,'SCAB1714435C2','Vazio','Lexmark International','50F0Z00',null,null))
```

Há algum modo de remover o primeiro e a último caractere de uma string?

Comment: E onde está a string que pretende remover?

Comment: Seu código rodou normal para mim: https://ideone.com/Y388jZ

Comment: Tem certeza que `conteudoLote` não é uma string com menos que dois caracteres?

Comment: Não minha string `conteudoLote` tem mais que dois caracteres, vou alterar minha pegunta com o conteúdo da variável

Comment: Para mim, isso funciona, [**veja aqui no ideone**](https://ideone.com/y16q0d). Além disso, essa sua string não tem nenhum `[` ou `]`.

Comment: Se a sua ideia é produzir um JSON, eu usaria `.replace('(', '[').replace(')',']')` ao invés de `.replace("[", "(").replace("]",")")`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa qual a diferença entre os `replaces`

Comment: @R.Santos São opostos. Eu troco parênteses por colchetes, enquanto que o seu troca colchetes por parênteses. Também estou usando replace de caracteres (com aspas simples) ao invés de replace de strings (com aspas duplas), que deve ter um desempenho um pouco melhor.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim a questão da troca de parenteses por colchetes eu notei, é que na verdade minha string original já é com colchetes por isso faço o `replace` assim, outra coisa que notei e que o erro ocorreu na verdade quando coloquei o `replace('Suprimento com Defeito e com Resíduo', 'Garantia').replace('Suprimento Bom e com Resíduo', 'Resíduo')` poderia tentar adicionar isso no seu codigo modelo para ver se o erro ocorre pra ti assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode fazer um substring do segundo caractere até o penúltimo, dessa forma:

```
String stringCortada = stringOriginal.substring(1, stringOriginal.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String removePrimeiroEUltimo(String x) {
    if (x == null) return null;
    if (x.length() <= 2) return "";
    return x.substring(1, x.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Realmente, a string dele pode ser nula ou ter menos que 2 caracteres, úncia forma que vejo de lançar aquela exceção

Comment: @Math Se for `null` daria `NullPointerException`. Acho que o caso dele é menos de 2 caracteres.

Comment: hum verdade....

Comment: Não minha string conteudoLote tem mais que dois caracteres, vou alterar minha pegunta com o conteúdo da variável

Answer (score 2):

Segue:

```
String myStr="[wdsd34svdf]";
System.out.println(myStr.substring(1, myStr.length()-1));
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846173/how-to-remove-first-and-last-character-of-a-string